# how would i write prepared sql statements rather than using real_escape PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
public $id;
public $filename;
public $type;
public $size;
public $description;
public $title;
```

this is what i am using now, which is bad,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photographgallery 
              (filename,type,size,description,title)
    VALUES ('$sanitized_filename', '$sanitized_type', '$sanitized_size', '$sanitized_description', '$sanitized_title')";
```

i was wondering if i could write a prepared statement for this, how would i go about it, i am stack. help.

Comment: Which API are you using? `mysql_*`, `mysqli` or `PDO`? (Hint: don't use `mysql_*`.)

Comment: @Darwin von Corax "mysqli"

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax mysqli_connect

Comment: here's the documentation: http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: You might find PDO is a little more pleasant to use since you can have named placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL you replace the variables with question-mark placeholders (`?`). Create a `mysqli_stmt` by passing your query to `mysqli::prepare`, then bind your variables to the placeholders with a call to `mysqli_stmt::bind_param`. Call `mysqli_stmt::execute`to perform the insert. It looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photographgallery 
            (filename, type, size, description, title)
          VALUES
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// The string 'ssiss' in the following means 'string, string, int, string, string'
//  and describes the types of the parameters.
$stmt->bind_param('ssiss', $filename, $type, $size, $description, $title);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();  // always clean up after yourself
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Your variables, however you get them.    
$filename = "name1";
$type = "type1";
$size = 100;
$desc = "test desc";
$title = "title"

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO photographgallery (filename, type, size, description, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssiss', $filename, $type, $size, $desc, $title); //Assuming the variables are string, string, int, string, string respectively
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Using the if around the code ensures that it only runs if the prepare statement has no errors. If there is an error the prepare statement returns false.